# Creating a Recursive Function for Number Sequence

Tags: c++, recursion

I know this is basic CS knowledge, but I still can't grasp the idea of doing a recursive function over a for loop. I'm still confused on the idea of recursion especially with numbers. Lets say there's a numerical sequence 3, 11, 27, 59, 123.... I know how to figure out the mathematical recursive sequence which is just An = An-1 + (8*(n-1)), but don't really know how to put this into a C++ recursive function.

Can someone outline the creation of a recursive function for the above numerical sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recursive functions have two "parts", the base case and the recursion. The base case is when your function stops recursing (and starts unwinding the call stack). Without the base the function just keeps calling itself until the stack overflow happens and the program is terminated by the OS.

The recursive part takes the initial problem (in your case finding the ith number in a sequence) and shrinks it. This happens until the base case is hit. So for finding the ith number in a sequence, let's say the 4th, you start looking for the 4th number, but that depends on the 3rd, which depends on the 2nd which depends on the first. The initial recursion shrinks the problem from the 4th number to the 3rd.

Here's a stab (not at all tested) at a recursive function for your sequence.

```
int recursive(int i) {
   // This is your base case, it prevents infinite recursion.
   if (i == 0) return 0; // Or whatever you base value is
   else {
     int sum = recursive(i-1) + 8 * (i-1);
     return sum;
   }
 }
```

Lots of times a recursive function can be done with a loop. However there are functions which require recursion. For instance, [Ackermann's Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AckermannFunction.html). A really good video on [Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7sm9dzFtEI)

Answer (score 1):

Basic recursive implementation of said function (proper values for your sequence are 3, 11, 27, 51, 83, 123, … btw):

```
int seq(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return 3;
    else
        return seq(n-1) + 8 * (n-1);
}
```

However, this implementation is not tail-recursive (therefore it will use stack, while iterative implementation would not). We can write tail-recursive version by introducing accumulator parameter:

```
int seq_r(int n, int acc)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return acc;
    else
        return seq_r(n-1, acc + 8 * (n-1));
}

int seq(int n)
{
    return seq_r(n, 3);
}
```

Or, same implementation but with seq_r hidden inside your function using lambda expressions:

```
#include <functional>

int seq(int n)
{
    std::function<int(int, int)> seq_r = [&] (int n, int acc) -> int {
        if (n <= 1)
            return acc;
        else
            return seq_r(n-1, acc + 8 * (n-1));
    };
    return seq_r(n, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your sequence function is defined as: `A[n] = A[n-1] + 8*(n-1)` then you need two things. 1) A structure to hold the sequence of numbers, and 2) a function or loop to produce those numbers. For the structure I will use a std::vector and the loop or function can be used as below:

## Loop

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> storage;

    // Seed the storage with a number since the sequence looks back.
    storage.push_back(3);

    // Define the maximum number count.
    int maxNum = 5;

    // Create the sequence by starting from n=1 since there are [n-1] terms.
    for(int n = 1; n <= maxNum; n++)
        storage.push_back(storage[n - 1] + 8*(n - 1));

    return 0;
}
```

## Function

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> storage;

void DoSequence(int maxNum, int n = 0)
{
    // Check the limit.
    if(n > maxNum)
        return;

    // Check seeding condition if adding the first element,
    // otherwise run the equation.
    if(n == 0)
        storage.push_back(3);
    else
        storage.push_back(storage[n - 1] + 8*(n-1));

    // Call the same function.
    DoSequence(maxNum, n + 1);
}

int main()
{
    // Call the recursive function with upper limit (n=5).
    DoSequence(5);

    return 0;
}
```

There are other ways to implement the details such as how `storage` is declared or handled but that is personal preference. Note: I did not test this code but hopefully you get the idea. In short, once you have your sequence function defined then create a loop or program function to generate the numbers.